# MVC 3 Saving checkbox state in db

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have one problem i am hoping someone will have time to look at. I have view as table in my mvc 3 test project. Inside table there is checkbox. I am trying to have that checkboxes to be saved whenever i click on them. I tried with java script, tried with lots of examples from internet but still no luck for me. Can someone help? :)

This is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.section)
        </td>
        <td>

  @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.check, new { onclick = "SomeMethod(this)" });

</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.idImovine }) 

           </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

   function SomeMethod(checkboxInput) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/Action',
            data: { newValue: checkboxInput.checked },
            success: success,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

</script>
```

This is my controller

```
   public JsonResult Action(bool newValue)
        {

            var model = con.pro.Single(r => r.id == id);


            TryUpdateModel(model);
            con.SubmitChanges();

            return Json(true)


        }
```

I am using linq to sql for access to db. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong, my intention is to have checkbox saved in dv whenever it is clicked, but that checkbox is getting clicked in a table which is coming from view and it needs to be saved to another tabe, so i am guessing i need to pass id which is inside view too, along with checkbox value.

Comment: Can you save the data when you click into submit button from your form or just when you select some checkbox?

Comment: answer from Shyju did the trick, now everything is working as intended. Ty all for responses, lots of nice ppl here :D. When i learn mvc 3 better will try to help like this to other pll :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to pass the ID of the record which is represented by the checkbox. So let's update your razor code like this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.check,
                                              new { @id=item.ID, @class="chks"});
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Now we will have some unobutrusive javascript which listens for the click event of the check box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

       $(document).on("click","input.chks", function (e) {
           var _this=$(this);
           var isChecked = _this.is(':checked');
           $.post("@Url.Action("Update","Home")?id="+_this.attr("id")+
                                          "&newValue="+isChecked,function(data){
                 // do something with the response
           });

       });
  });

</script>
```

Now make sure your `Update` method is accepting 2 parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(int id,bool newValue)
{
   //do your saving here.
  return Json(true); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was just want i needed. Everything works fine now, checkbox is saved like it needs to be :)

Answer (score 1):

if you're using POST, then your action should be marked accordingly

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Action(bool newValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an `Id` in your Model and then do this in your view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.check, 
    new { @dataid = item.Id, onclick = "SomeMethod(this)" });
```

Then do your ajax post like this:

```
function SomeMethod(checkboxInput) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/Action',
        data: { newValue: $(checkboxInput).is(':checked'), id: $(checkboxInput).attr('dataid') },
        success: success,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

And accept it in your controller like this:

```
public JsonResult Action(bool newValue, int id)
{
    // do your saving here
}
```

Comment: I got it now, mister Shyju answer was what i needed. I was close with my solution but i couldnt figure what is wrong :D Now i know. Thank you to mister von v :)